# Metro App StorageFile GetThumbnailAsync Background

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5, winrt-async

In a **Metro App**, when retrieving the Thumbnail of a `StorageFile` using the `GetThumbnailAsync()` method, the `Background` `Color` is a **Dark Blue/Navy Blue**.

Is it possible to override this `Color`? I would like the `Background` to be `Transparent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh465350),

> *The thumbnail is an icon on a background of appropriate size. The background color is determined by the app that is associated with the file.*

Combined with the following note:

> **Note**  *If the associated app is a Windows Store app, the app's tile background color is used.*

If your app has an association with the file, just make sure your apps `Background` color is `Transparent` (not 100% sure you can do that, actually).

The other option is to use something like WriteableBitmapEx to find every pixel of the tile color, then turn those pixels to `Transparent`. Shouldn't be too absolutely terrible, but will have an overhead (naturally).

Hope this helps and Happy Coding!